# Can I turn a laptop into a PS2?

Tags: ps2, bios

So, I was thinking.

If I have the PS2 bios, and PS2 games, *what stops me from flashing my laptop bios into the PS2 bios?*

*Does anything stop me from reverting it back?*

So, my overall question is, can I flash my laptop bios or desktop bios, and replace it with a PS2 bios?

Comment: Why would you think this is possible?  You're talking completely different hardware.

Comment: @Frank: Presumably the OP thoguht it was possible because, like many people, they don't have a good understanding of what difference hardware is. To many people a computer is a computer - they don't know about different CPUs, motherboards, GPUs, etc. So to somebody not familiar with the concepts involved this is a reasonable question. That having been said I am a little worried about somebody who doesn't know this stuff about hardware wanting to flash BIOSes...

Comment: @Chris I believe a small amount of research would've answered this handily, and not doing so shows a startling lack of knowledge about hardware that they should know, if they know about flashing the BIOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.
PS2 is a special case hardware.
Your computer BIOS/UEFI is a software specific to only that motherboard you are using. There is an emulator called PCSX2 which you can use to run PS2 games on a PC.